# Vue PWA i18n in Service Worker

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, service-worker, vue-cli, vue-pwa

for a university project my team and I have developed a Webapp using Vue.js (Vue-Cli).
For translating the app we have integrated vue-i18n.

Recently we upgraded the app to the use of a service-worker including backend triggered push notifications.

I'm now wondering on how to handle different Languages inside the service worker.
At least when using the vue-cli-pwa Plugin for the service worker integration, there is no way to access other modules/components out of the box, therefore I can't access the translation module.

Is there any way to do this?
Or is the approach of handling translation for push notifications inside the service worker completely wrong in general?
I can not seem to find any information on push notifications and i18n.

Thank you!